# My column highcharts is not rendering any data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, bar-chart

I am trying to create a column highchart what I eventually want to add drilldown to. Right now I am starting by just wanting to create a simple column chart. My code is not rendering anything.

WHat am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

JSON:

```
var json = [{
 hp: "Harry",
 starts: 42,
 completes: 142
}, {
  hp: "Ron",
  starts: 2,
  completes: 90
}, {
  hp: "Hermione",
  starts: 75,
  completes: 175
}];
```

JavaScript:

```
 var series1 = {
 name: '',
 data: []
 }
 json.forEach(elem => {
  series1.data.push({
    x: +elem.hp,
    y: elem.starts
   });
 });

 Highcharts.chart('container', {
 chart: {
   type: 'column'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
   series: [
     series1
   ]
   });
```

My Chart:

[image: my chart]

I also don't need the legend. Why is my chart not rendering?

Comment: What are you trying to display here? What should your chart show?

Comment: hp on the xaxis and starts on the yaxis. So 3 columns.

Comment: @Clafou. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a quick example here: https://jsfiddle.net/3bvopn5f/

From what I understand, if you want to create categories with a bar chart, you should include data for the other categories too (either `null` or `0`).

Here are some interesting highcharts options :

```
chart: {
   type: 'column'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: json.map(elem => elem.hp)
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Harry Potter',
    data: [42, 0, 0]
  }, {
    name: 'Ron',
    data: [0, 2, 0]
  }, {
    name: 'Hermione',
    data: [0, 0, 75]
  }],
```

With data manipulation, a possibility would be to do this :

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    serie1.push({
    name: json[i].hp,
    data: json.map(v => v.hp === json[i].hp ? v.starts : 0),
  })
}
```

Here's the fiddle with your data manipulated to fit the chart : https://jsfiddle.net/znwauftv/